# R -- spread function -- difference between using column name directly vs df$column

Tags: r

This is my script

```
 weather_long <- spread(weather,weather$element,weather$value)
```

It got error:

```
Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a character vector
```

But it works in this way:

```
weather_long <- spread(weather,element,value)
```

To me both of them are the same script so I don't understand why R thinks they are different?'

Sample Data

[image]

Comment: please provide a sample data.

Comment: They aren't equivalent - `spread` is `spread(data=weather, key=element, value=value)` where `key` and `value` are *names* of columns inside `weather`, not the actual columns of data like `weather$element` and `weather$value` are. This is done so it can be typically called by piping like `weather %>% spread(element,value)` in the tidyverse set of packages.

Comment: And as a general rule in `tidyverse` packages, you should not reference the frame when it is expecting non-standard evaluation. For instance, `group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>% summarize(a = sum(disp))` is correct and far different from `group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>% summarize(a = sum(mtcars$disp))` (which does not error or warn).